# Two errors with syntax

Tags: bash, shell, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

The issue is that I have this error:
`line 65: unexpected EOF while looking for matching` )'`and also it may be regarded to second issue:`syntax error: unexpected end of file` Because script is closed correctly I think, for now most major is to check what is going on with line 65.

And the LINE 65 is this line: `USER_CHECK=$(sqlplus -S /nolog <<:EOF`

```
while IFS="," read -r ID New; do

    USER_CHECK=$(sqlplus -S /nolog <<:EOF <-- This is line 65
    CONNECT ${ORA_USER}/${ORA_USER}@${ORA_STRING};
    set colsep ,
    set linesize 32767
    set pagesize 9999
    set markup CSV on
    set feedback on
    set heading on

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATTRIBUTES WHERE USER_ID = '${ID}';

    quit
    :EOF
    )
```

I tried to make it run in different ways, but nothing is popping up that can solve the issue. Even chatgpt says its correct :D

Comment: Asking ChatGPT often merely confirms that asking ChatGPT is not a good idea.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.